# Compare two dates with datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I ve been trying to compare two dates:

i get the first with:

```
    now =  datetime.datetime.now()
    data_loc=datetime.date(now.year,now.month,now.day)
```

the second one like:

```
    date_to_compare=datetime.date(2018,2,13)
```

now i would like something like that:

```
    if (data_loc-date_to_compare) < 60:
        do something
```

This is the error i get:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to compare `timedelta` to another `timedelta`:

```
if (data_loc-date_to_compare) < datetime.timedelta(days=60):
```

Comment: thanks, i had already tried but with onother logic and i got some errors.It was really simple. Thanks again

Comment: Please post your solution.